# Stuck on problem about dimensional analysis

Tags: dimensional-analysis

This is the first part of a long exercise:

> We consider heat conduction in a rod of length $l$. The rod is assumed to be thermally
> isolated everywhere. Starting with a given temperature distribution $u(x, 0)$ over the rod, we
> are interested in the time evolution of the temperature profile $u(x, t)$. As will be explained
> in Example 2.3d in Chapter 2, the speed of the heat conduction along the rod is determined
> by the so-called thermal conductivity $\kappa$. The dimension of $\kappa$ is $\frac{L^2}{T}$ . As an initial profile
> we take a distribution which is everywhere vanishing except for a peak in the origin:
> $$ u(x,0) = u_0\delta(x), $$
> where $\delta(x)$ is the so-called delta function.

> a) Determine the dimensions of the constant $u_0$. To that end, integrate the initial condition over some interval containing $x=0$ and use the properties of the delta function.

I'm at a loss how to solve this. I know that $u$ is a temperature and its dimension is $\frac{ML^2}{T^2}$. However, what happens with its dimension when I integrate? It seems to me that I should integrate over $x=0$ to $x=l$, but I do not know how to incorporate the properties of the delta function. I do know that if we integrate over a domain $I$ containing zero, it follows that
$$\int_I \delta(x)v(x)\,dx = v(0),$$
for a continuous function $v(x)$.
I would appreciate it if someone could give me a hint, since I cannot continue with the rest of the exercise without solving this part first.

Comment: Note that the dimensions of $\int_I \delta(x)v(x)dx$ are the same as $\delta(x)v(x)dx$.

Comment: So an integral always has the same dimensions as the integrand?

Comment: Theres an extra factor of $dx$ (which has the units of the variable you are integrating over)